# I can't access into my Ubuntu account 14.04

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, accounts

For disgrace I have asked advice in "chiedi Ubuntu" forum - the Italian version of ask Ubuntu - and for following their advice, I can't get anymore in my Ubuntu account due to internal errors of the operative system.

Basically, I have just entered these commands " sudo apt-get autoclean " and " sudo apt-get autoremove " (the reason was that my Ubuntu became too slow) but now after entering the password for accessing into my account, the operative system just stuck - as if it can't load properly.

They then suggested me to use Ubuntu live to save my data (I have important data inside my account) but I can't find the folder (I hope I have not lost them! But I think I haven't)...

In short, I have 2 problems: first, I want to be sure my data are ok and I would like to save them in an external support (also, I would like to recover the list of my favourites websites from the browser). Second, obviously I would like to enter my account (if I am successful in the first step, saving data, I can consider also to reinstall the operative system).

Maybe I was too long... but I hope I was clear!

Ps. I am writing here because they don't answer always and it is already days I can't solve this problem

Comment: Please add whether you have physical access to the system and whether you data is encrypted and if it is in which way.

Comment: If I well remember data are encrypted but I don't know in which way. Yes, I have my laptop with me:) (now I am writing from another, of course)

Comment: Create a live medium, boot into a live session, open Nautilus, open the system partition if possible, then go from the to home/youUserName and look if you can open an arbitrary file. Tell if this works or at which point it stopped working.

Comment: See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: I have the live of Ubuntu 12.04 - my operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 - is it fine? I tried to write in the dash of the live session "Nautilus" but it doesn't find this program - is gparted good as well for the task suggested?

Comment: I think I have found the folder with the data I am looking for but I cannot access it from the live as Ubuntu reminds me that I have no privileges